# processing tuples in SML

Tags: list, size, tuples, sml

I have an assignment where I need to take a tuple and return another tuple, of the same size, with certain elements changed. The problem is I don't know how to process a tuple of an undefined size. The function needs to be able to process tuples of any size. My idea was to make the tuple into a list that i could process much more easily, by making a recursive helper function to take element #1 of the tuple and cons it to a call to the same function which would give element #2 consed onto the recursion again until there are no elements left, but this just gives an error when i get to #n+1 where n is the total number of items in the tuple. 
Am I going about this the wrong way? is there a way to find the size of a tuple? is there a way to handle this error? I know about exception handling, but I'm not sure how to apply it to his case, if even possible.

the question is create a function named subst, such that subst (e’,x) e = [e’/x]e i.e. the function subst will replace any free occurrence of the variable x in the expression e' by the expression e. Add the appropriate case for tuples.

Answer (score 1):

> The function needs to be able to process tuples of any size.

This cannot be done. Tuples of different sizes are completely different and unrelated types; there is no type of function that is polymorphic enough to be both `'a * 'b -> ...` and `'a * 'b * 'c -> ...`, unless it's simply of type `'a -> ...` (i.e., it accepts any argument at all, with no special understanding of tuples).

(The built-in notations `# 1`, `# 2`, etc. are overloaded functions that work for any tuple type, but this is magic that you can't duplicate. You can't even write something like `val f = # 1` without giving the compiler enough information to infer `f`'s exact type; you'd have to write e.g. `val f : 'a * 'b -> 'a = # 1` to specify that `f` returns the first field *of a pair*.)

Comment: then i have no clue how to do this assignment... I have to make a program that looks through a tuple of undetermined size for certain variables, then replace them with others.

Comment: @Arsarcanum: You have probably misunderstood your assignment, because what you describe is literally impossible. Standard ML simply does not have any concept of "a tuple of undetermined size".

Comment: I was confused by it too, so I specifically asked my professor "do you mean the tuple can be any size?" (because the assignment said tuple of (t0, t1, ..., tn) and she said yes...

Comment: @Arsarcanum: Can you edit your question to include the exact text of the assignment?

Comment: create a function named subst, such that subst (e’,x) e = [e’/x]e
i.e. the function subst will replace any free occurrence of the variable x in the expression e' by the expression e.
Add the appropriate case for tuples.

Comment: (And be sure to include the definition of the "expression" data-type. Standard ML doesn't have Lisp-style macros, so "expression" here can't mean an SML expression; rather, it must mean something manipulable inside the function.)

Comment: oh I solved it, thanks for the help. I was confusing tuple with Tuple, which is actually a LIST type in the assignment... that probably could have been clearer.

Comment: @Arsarcanum: That makes sense. I'm glad you figured it out. :-)